# When generating files with docstrip, can I insert the output file name anywhere besides preamble and postamble?

Tags: automation, docstrip

I'm generating source files from a `.dtx` file using docstrip. I would like the literal file name to be placed in the argument to a `\ProvidesFile` command.

Right now I'm doing it something like this:

```
%<*driver>
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
    \file{foo.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{foo}}
    \file{bar.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{bar}}
}
\endbatchfile
%</driver>
%<*!driver>
\documentclass{article}
\ProvidesFile
%<foo>{foo.tex}
%<bar>{bar.tex}
%<foo>\title{Foo}
%<bar>\title{Bar}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello, world!
\end{document}
%</!driver>
```

This works fine, but seems a bit repetitive. Especially since the generated files
have a preamble like this:

```
%%
%% This is file `foo.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% ...
\documentclass{article}
\ProvidesFile
{foo.tex}

\title{Foo}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `foo.tex'.
```

The interface for declaring custom preambles and postambles provide the `\outFileName` command for this purpose. It would be great if I could also insert `\outFileName` in the main file.

I'm aware of the `%<@@=module>` guard, but it doesn't quite suit this purpose. For one thing, it adds `__` to the beginning of the `module` replacement text. For another, I'd still have to write a line with the generated file name in it, when I really just want to write it only in the `\generate` block.

Another idea I had was to use `lua` to read the file, extract the file name from the first couple of lines, and rewrite the file inserting it in place of a name like `@OUTFILENAME@`. I'm driving the file generation with an `l3build` script, so I almost know how to do that by hooking into the `unpack` function or adding to `docinit_hook`.

Maybe I don't need this at all and I can just use `\ProvidesFile{\jobname.tex}`. The main reason I am inserting a `\ProvidesFile` line into a `.tex` file is so that I can use the `readprov` package, and get the file version/date from this line. But those are done with `\UseVersionOf{\jobname.tex}` etc. already. So `\ProvidesFile{\jobname.tex}` has the effect I want.  But I do kind of feel like `\ProvidesFile` should declare the name of the file itself, and not the name of the job.